# Django Snippets Required

Tags: django, open-source, django-models

I'm a really tight schedule to code up a prototype for a website. I'm working with Django and am just starting out. Can you suggest open source Django snippets for the following:

1) A User Registration system (Registration/Authentication/Sessions)
2) A Rating System (Preferably a x/10 or 5 stars rating system)
3) A tags based search system

I'm really a noob and I need to get the version 1 out in 4 hours. So I'll just use open source code and modify it. I will make sure to keep the final version open sourced as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the main Django guy from our team bailed because his mom is in the hospital. I'm looking for a PHP framework now because I'm better at PHP than Python. Please check my new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760669/creating-a-social-networking-website-in-php

Comment: How does one use a django snippet? :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Pinax Project](http://pinaxproject.com/).  That should cover #1 (OpenID) and #3 (tagging).

Comment: Grrr... You beat me to it.  :-)

Comment: it's about time I beat someone to it!  Normally I'm on the losing end :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your basic Django installation will provide users, authentication, and session handling right out of the box.  For your user registration needs, you might consider [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home).  It's written by [James Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28070/james-bennett), a well-respected Django contributor.  For tagging, I've always used [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/).

I've never used a rating system in a Django application, but you might consider using [django-ratings](http://code.google.com/p/django-ratings/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I never searched for your exact two examples, but [django snippets](http://www.djangosnippets.org/) is usually a really good place to start when looking for django code examples.