# Creating a Social Networking Website in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp, codeigniter, buddypress

What's the fastest, open-source PHP social networking framework that can help me get a working prototype in four hours? I'm looking at something that can handle profiles, where each profile can make multiple posts, and each post can be rated by the community? I'm looking at BuddyPress with Wordpress MU? Is this achievable, or should I go with CakePHP or CodeIgniter? Are there any plugins out there that you can recommend? Thanks a lot for your feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have looked at both, BuddyPress seems to have more off the shelf plugins as it is in it's self a plugin of wordpress. buddypress seems a little eaiser to develop for when it comes to db than elgg.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Elgg](http://www.elgg.org/) – it seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: I checked it out, and it looks great! Can it be modified to suit my requirements? I mean how good is the doc and flexibility? Sorry for trying to push too much for answers, but I don't really have time for failing. Thanks so much!

Comment: The docs (http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/) is very extensive, and Elgg itself got very flexible code. I'd recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Not in PHP, but if you need that with such short deadline you can get a social networking site ready for free with [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) and [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) (Python).

Comment: That was the initial plan, but the main Python programmer bailed and I need something in PHP, as I'm better with PHP. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are looking at creating a website with such a strict deadline, you'd be better off trying to use a pre-built CMS such as Joomla, Drupal, or a host of other ones out there that are PHP. Most (if not all) are open source meaning you can do development on your own to expand or modify the functionality.

Comment: He need a social network not a content management system.

Comment: You can make a social network out of a CMS. I'm not saying it's ideal, but given a deadline of 4 hours it's not unthinkable.

Answer (score 0):

cakephp or elgg.